# Entity Framework - query specifying inherited type for navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

So I have an entity that has a navigation property which has a type with a class hierarchy. (entity names changed to protect the guilty)

```
class ParentEntity
{
  virtual ChildEntity TheProperty { get; set; }
  virtual string AnotherProperty { get; set; }
  virtual string AnotherProperty2 { get; set; }
}

class ChildEntity
{
}

class ChildSubEntity : ChildEntity
{
  virtual string InterestingProperty { get; set; }
}
```

How can I query for ParentClass entities, with one of my query conditions being where TheProperty is of type ChildSubClass and InterestingProperty has a particular value?

I've tried

```
ObjectContext context = GetContext();
var result = context.ParentEntities.
  Where(e => e.AnotherProperty == AnotherInterestingValue).
  Where(e => e.TheProperty is ChildSubEntity).
  Where(e => ((ChildSubEntity)e.TheProperty).
    InterestingProperty == InterestingValue).
  ToList();
```

And get the error "Unable to cast the type 'ChildEntity' to type 'ChildSubEntity'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.".

I'm having to settle for flattening the list, and applying this condition after the data has been retrieved from the entity store. Is it possible to write this condition in a form LINQ to Entities will accept?

To be clear, this is a simplification, I'm actually applying a number of conditions programmatically, building a query expression using [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx), with some of the conditions being on properties of ParentEntity, some on ParentEntity, and some on other child entities of ParentEntity.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to use `OfType` its correctly resolved by `LINQ to Entities`. Use it against `ChildEntity` collection and select `ParentEntities` related to selected `ChildEntity` objects.

```
ObjectContext context = GetContext();
var result = context.ChildEntities.OfType<ChildSubEntity>
.Where(e => e.InterestingProperty == InterestingValue)
.SelectMany(e = > e.ParentEntity)
.ToList();
```

Comment: Good answer. However I have numerous other criteria on ParentEntity that need to be met, I'll edit the question to make that clear.

Comment: Just add `Where` in `SelectMany` to filter `ParentEntity`

Comment: Oh, now that *is* interesting. I'll have a play and get back to you.

Comment: I'm having some trouble making this play nice with my unit of work framework, but that's my issue, not yours :-)